# checking validity of Sudoku Board. C program

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I am currently creating a project that checks if a given 9x9 sudoku table follows the rules of sudoku. The table is stored in a multidimensional array (board[9][9])I am stuck on how to correctly check through each 3x3 sub-grid for duplicate numbers. I have already established checks for numbers outside of 0(blanks) and 9(max value) as well as checks for duplicates in each row and column. I have managed two create 4 nested for loops that successfully loop through each 3x3 box, but I am unsure how to check the values in the box for duplicates. My definition of a duplicate is two cells that contain the same number (other than zero which is reserved as blanks in my program). Below is my code so far. This code checks that each number in the first column of each 3x3 subgrid is valid but fails to check the other 2 columns of each box.

```
for(int x=0;x<9;x=x+3){                 //iterates through each 3x3 sub box going through each row. Temp B compares each value to all other values in box.
    for(y=0;y<9;y=y+3){
        for(j=x;j<x+3;j++){
            tempB = board[j][k];
                for(k=y;k<y+3;k++) {
                    for (z = x; z < x + 3; z++) {
                        if (z != j && tempB == board[z][k] && tempB != 0) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What keeps you from adapting the method for rows and columns to the boxes?

Comment: How about a 9-sized array and counting the number of each possible digit in the entry accessed by using the digit (-1) as index. If you do not get 0 or > 1 you are good.

Answer (score 1):

Why nobody provides a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ever?

As Yunnosch suggested you can just count occurrences of the numbers in an array. Remember to skip empty cells (0).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int board_noduplicates(int board[9][9]) 
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x += 3) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 9; y += 3) {
            int count[10] = { 0 };
            for(int j = x; j < x + 3; ++j) {
                for(int k = y; k < y + 3; ++k) {
                    int cur = board[j][k];
                    if(cur > 0 && count[cur] > 0) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    ++count[cur];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int board1[9][9] = {
        {1,2,3, 0,0,0, 4,5,6,},
        {0,0,0, 1,0,0, 0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0, 0,0,8, 0,0,0,},

        {4,5,6, 2,0,0, 7,8,9,},
        {0,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0, 0,0,3, 0,0,0,},

        {7,8,9, 4,0,0, 1,2,3,},
        {0,0,0, 0,5,0, 0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0, 0,0,6, 0,0,0,},
    };
    int board2[9][9] = {
        {1,2,3, 0,0,0, 4,5,6,},
        {0,0,0, 1,0,0, 0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0, 0,0,8, 0,0,0,},

        {4,5,6, 2,0,0, 7,8,9,},
        {0,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,0,},
        {0,0,5, 0,0,3, 0,0,0,}, // <-- duplicate

        {7,8,9, 4,0,0, 1,2,3,},
        {0,0,0, 0,5,0, 0,0,0,},
        {0,0,0, 0,0,6, 0,0,0,},
    };  
    
    printf("board_noduplicates(board1) -> %d\n", board_noduplicates(board1));
    printf("board_noduplicates(board2) -> %d\n", board_noduplicates(board2));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could also store the elements of current sub-grid into a single `int` instead of an array of 10 `ints`, provided that we know that element's min value is 1 and max is 9.

Comment: @frumle True, but why? Wouldn't it be just harder to read later?